# Find values which sum to 0 in Excel with many items

Tags: c#, excel, performance, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

I have to find each subset in a enough big list, 500/1000 items that are positive and negative and are decimal, whiches sum to 0. I'm not an expert so I read many and many articles and solutions, and then I wrote my code. Datas comes from Excel worksheet and I would to mark found sums there.
Code works in this way:

- Initally I find all pair that sum to 0
- Then I put the remains sums into a list and take the combinations within 20 items, beacause I know the it is not possible bigger combination sum to 0
- In these combinations I search if one combinations sums to 0 and save it in result list, else save sum in dictionary as key and then I'll search if dictionary contains next sums (so I check pairs of these subsets)
- I keep track of the index so I can reach and modify the cells

To found solutions is enough fast but when I want elaborate the results in Excel become really slow. I don't take care about find all solutions but I want to find as max as possible in a short time.

What do you think about this solution? How can I improve the speed? How can I skip easly the sums that are already taken? And how can mark the cells fastly in my worksheet, beacuse now here is the bottleneck of the program?

I hope it is enough clear :) Thanks to everybody for any help

Here my code of the combination's part:

```
        List<decimal> listDecimal = new List<decimal>();
        List<string> listRange = new List<string>();
        List<decimal> resDecimal = new List<decimal>();
        List<IEnumerable<decimal>> resDecimal2 = new List<IEnumerable<decimal>>();
        List<IEnumerable<string>> resIndex = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
        Dictionary<decimal, int> dicSumma = new Dictionary<decimal, int>();
        foreach (TarkistaSummat.CellsRemain el in list)
        {
            decimal sumDec = Convert.ToDecimal(el.Summa.Value);
            listDecimal.Add(sumDec);
            string row = el.Summa.Cells.Row.ToString();
            string col = el.Summa.Cells.Column.ToString();
            string range = el.Summa.Cells.Row.ToString() + ":" + el.Summa.Cells.Column.ToString();
            listRange.Add(range);
        }

        var subsets = new List<IEnumerable<decimal>> { new List<decimal>() };
        var subsetsIndex = new List<IEnumerable<string>> { new List<string>() };

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 20)
            {
                List<IEnumerable<decimal>> parSubsets = subsets.GetRange(i, i + 20);
                List<IEnumerable<string>> parSubsetsIndex = subsetsIndex.GetRange(i, i + 20);
                var Z = parSubsets.Select(x => x.Concat(new[] { listDecimal[i] }));
                //var Zfound = Z.Select(x => x).Where(w => w.Sum() ==0);
                subsets.AddRange(Z.ToList());
                var Zr = parSubsetsIndex.Select(x => x.Concat(new[] { listRange[i] }));
                subsetsIndex.AddRange(Zr.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                var T = subsets.Select(y => y.Concat(new[] { listDecimal[i] }));
                //var Tfound = T.Select(x => x).Where(w => w.Sum() == 0);
                //resDecimal2.AddRange(Tfound);
                //var TnotFound = T.Except(Tfound);
                subsets.AddRange(T.ToList());
                var Tr = subsetsIndex.Select(y => y.Concat(new[] { listRange[i] }));
                subsetsIndex.AddRange(Tr.ToList());
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < subsets.Count; i++)
        {
            decimal sumDec = subsets[i].Sum();

            if (sumDec == 0m)
            {
                resDecimal2.Add(subsets[i]);
                resIndex.Add(subsetsIndex[i]);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if(dicSumma.ContainsKey(sumDec * -1))
                {
                    dicSumma.TryGetValue(sumDec * -1, out int index);
                    IEnumerable<decimal> addComb = subsets[i].Union(subsets[index]);
                    resDecimal2.Add(addComb);
                    var indexComb = subsetsIndex[i].Union(subsetsIndex[index]);
                    resIndex.Add(indexComb);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!dicSumma.ContainsKey(sumDec))
                    {
                        dicSumma.Add(sumDec, i);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < resIndex.Count; i++)
        {
            //List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();
            foreach(string el in resIndex[i])
            {
                string[] split = el.Split(':');
                Range cell = actSheet.Cells[Convert.ToInt32(split[0]), Convert.ToInt32(split[1])];
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6;
            }
```

}
}

Comment: How fast is it now? How fast do you want it to be (note: 'as fast as it can be' is not an acceptable answer)?

Comment: Your call to `if(dicSumma.ContainsKey(sumDec * -1))` is unnecessary - the `TryGetValue` after it is sufficient.

Comment: Hi, now until the last for usually last less than 30 sec. But the last cycle that mark the results on the worksheet it's really slow and can last many minutes, I think due to Range type of variable, but I'm not sure. I'm thinking if it's possible make it more efficient. I would complete the process at max in 1-2 minutes.

Comment: When you profiled it, where was most of the time spent?